# vb.net how do i add long text into csv

Tags: vb.net, csv, datagridview

hello this is my firs thread , 
i'm trying to convert description of this page (https://www.tokopedia.com/indoislamicstore/cream-zaitun-arofah)
with regex and replace `<br/>` tag with new line and convert it to csv .

the datagridview it's alright but the csv got screwed

this is my code :

```
Dim dskrip As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("<p itemprop=""description"" class=""mt-20"">(.*?)\<\/p>\<\/div>")
        Dim dskripm As MatchCollection = dskrip.Matches(rssourcecode0)

        For Each itemdskrm As Match In dskripm
            getdeskripsinew = itemdskrm.Groups(1).Value
        Next
Dim deskripsinew As String = Replace(getdeskripsinew, ",", ";")
        Dim deskripsitotal As String = Replace(deskripsinew, "<br/>", Environment.NewLine)
        '   ListView1.s = Environment.NewLine & deskripsinew
        txtDeskripsi.Text = deskripsitotal
        datascrapes.ColumnCount = 5
        datascrapes.Columns(0).Name = "Title"
        datascrapes.Columns(1).Name = "Price"
        datascrapes.Columns(2).Name = "Deskripsi"
        datascrapes.Columns(3).Name = "Gambar"
        datascrapes.Columns(4).Name = "Total Produk"
        Dim row As String() = New String() {getname, totalprice, deskripsitotal, directoryme + getfilename, "10"}
        datascrapes.Rows.Add(row)
        Dim filePath As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) & "\" & "Tokopedia_Upload.csv"
        Dim delimeter As String = ","
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder
        For i As Integer = 0 To datascrapes.Rows.Count - 1
            Dim array As String() = New String(datascrapes.Columns.Count - 1) {}
            If i.Equals(0) Then
                For j As Integer = 0 To datascrapes.Columns.Count - 1
                    array(j) = datascrapes.Columns(j).HeaderText
                Next
                sb.AppendLine(String.Join(delimeter, array))
            End If
            For j As Integer = 0 To datascrapes.Columns.Count - 1
                If Not datascrapes.Rows(i).IsNewRow Then
                    array(j) = datascrapes(j, i).Value.ToString
                End If
            Next
            If Not datascrapes.Rows(i).IsNewRow Then
                sb.AppendLine(String.Join(delimeter, array))
            End If
        Next
        File.WriteAllText(filePath, sb.ToString)
```

[this is the csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSZyN.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where your problem is looking at the CSV file, but there are certain cases where you'll want to quote the values for a CSV. There's no official spec but [RFC 4180](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt) is often used as an unofficial standard. I would recommend using a library like [CSV Helper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/)

Comment: i mean how can i line break in single cell csv ,, if i use vbCrLf or Environment.NewLine the columns deskripsi got screwed ,, im sorry i have bad english :o

Comment: Both will work, you need to put quotes around your text though.